# .NET Dynamic Search Function

Tags: c#, .net, linq, search, dynamic

I am trying to create a search function that will read from the database to look through multiple columns and return if all keywords (delimited by space) have been used.

Currently I have something a long the lines of

```
db.Persons.Where(
 q=> 
    (keywords.Count() > 0)
    ||
    (
        keywords.Any(k => k.firstName.ToUpper().Contains(k)
        ||
        keywords.Any(k => k.lastName.ToUpper().Contains(k)
        ||
        keywords.Any(k => k.address.ToUpper().Contains(k)
    )
   )
```

However, I would like it to make sure that each keyword is in at least one column. Is this possible in LINQ or do I need to loop through it externally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
db.Persons.Where(q =>
    {
        string[] values = new string[] { q.firstName, q.lastName, q.address };
        return keywords.All(k => values.Any(v => v.ToUpper().Contains(k));
    });
```